# Why is scanf printing its input in the Nios 2 IDE?

Tags: c, nios

A very simple program is not even working.

```
int main ()
{
  int  n; 
  while (scanf("%d", &n) > 0)
  return 0;
}
```

The above I would expect to only read to input but it also prints the input:

```
2
2
3
3
```

I would have expected the above behavior if I had also this line in the while loop but I don't:

`printf("%d\n", n);`

Can you explain?

### Update

There is nothing in the answers that explain why this is happening. And no setting in the Nios 2 IDE for local echo turned on or off. And if there were it probably would not be dafeult causing unexpected output. And this program also prints its input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int  n; 
  while (scanf("%d", &n) > 0)
    ;
  return 0;
}
```

So this Nios 2 IDE which is based on Eclipse is nobody's choice since you cannot figure out why it is behaving in a way it shouldn't

Comment: Did you try compiling your code in another environment to see if it happens as well?

Comment: The code you posted above should return after one "scan", not two. Are you sure that's _exactly_ the code you're using?

Comment: It prints nothing. See http://ideone.com/QmF8KR

Comment: I think you considered input on your terminal as output!

Comment: Well, did you have that line somewhere else?

Comment: I'm using the Nios 2 IDE. I can try it in another environment but the result wouldn't answer why I get results that scanf is printing its input.

Comment: scanf isn't printing its input. Try removing scanf and replace it with sleep and your environment will still echo whatever you type as input.

Comment: @dontomaso My environment doesn't even have a sleep statement. `undefined reference to `sleep'` even though I include the library. So nothing works as expected. Code formatting is also completely broken in this broken environment.

Comment: Do you think it could have a busy-wait loop instead? It does not matter what it is. Your problem is not related to scanf.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about too localized, random and/or not reproducible beginner problem, unlikely to help anybody else. You may please delete my question since it also could have the opposite effect when looking for information about this development (FPGA Altera DE2). The actual problem was solved and my development environment for this type of work is now stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 candidates

1. Your terminal I/O has an unneeded local echo turned on.  Thus an OS issue, not a issue of this program.
2. Missing `;` at end of `while()` invokes expected results.  The code as posted should simple read some input and then immediately exit.  This is not as the OP recounts.  Suspect it is a mis-transcription of the problem.
   [edit]  Now see *all* of @alk solution.  Certainly something is in the OP's real code that is not visible in the post -maybe due to mixed `\r` and `\r\n` and `\n`?

   `// Was it a typo that the OP did not have a`;`at the end?`
   `while (scanf("%d", &n) > 0)`

Comment: If I use the `;` then there is no difference and `scanf` prints its input.

Comment: The expected difference of `;` is that without it, you should only be able to enter data once, then exit.  With `;`, you should be able to enter numeric data multiple times, then exit on invalid data or EOF.

Comment: Try entering non-numeric list "X".  If "X" "X" appears, we know the issue is tied to `stdin`.  If something like "X" "0" appears, its more related to some conversion of `scanf("%d").

Comment: If I enter "X" then "X" appears. I'm running it in the Nios 2 console IDE that might have local echo turned on, it's not behaving like it should.

Comment: And there appears to be absolutely no setting to control this in the IDE for any local echo turned on, and why would it be turned on by default? How come I'm having this much problems with a trivial program?

Answer (score -1):

Most probably your code looked like this:

```
int main ()
{
  int  n; 
  while (scanf("%d", &n) > 0)                                                                                           printf("%d\n", n);
  return 0;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------ scroll right >>> --------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How would that print anything?

Comment: Oh, very droll. I think you might need to add a hint, no scroll bar shows up in chrome.

Comment: No it isn't. Why does not even a simple program work? I hate Eclipse.

Answer (score -7):

`scanf()` returns integer which is number of parameters given as input. In your case `scanf("%d",&n)` returns 1.

You can check this as ref-
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/119407-scanf-return-values.html

Comment: This is not the answer!

Comment: This doesn't explain why it is printing a value at all.

Comment: I am compiling in GCC...In my case it is not printing value